# Delegate method not being run on UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I am building an Windows Form-based app that listens on a port and when it receives a specific command, it opens a window (Form) that requests input.

My problem is that even though I am using a delegated method to open the window, only the window furniture/border is drawn.  The contents of the form are not rendered at all.

From searching other answers on S.O., there seem to be two causes for this:

1. `InitializeComponent()` not being called
2. Trying to open the window from a non-UI thread

It appears that #2 is my problem.  When I compare the ManagedThreadId in the form constructor and from the callback delegate, they are different.

As far as I can tell from the docs, the delegate should ensure that the callback is run on the UI thread.
**Can anyone suggest why it isn't?**

Below is a simplified version of what my code looks like.

**The form**

```
public wPrompt(bool silent, bool listen)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 1

   // Register a handler for scan requests received via the network
   SocketListener.OpenFormRequest += OpenFormCommandHandler;
   // Class that contains the code to open a socket and listen for commands
   SocketListener.StartListening();
}

private void wPrompt_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 3
}

// The callback that gets called by the delegate
private void OpenFormCommandHandler()
{
   // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 3

   // Open the form
   Visible = true;
}
```

**The SocketListener class**

```
class SocketListener
{
   public delegate void OpenFormRequestEventHandler();
   public static event OpenFormRequestEventHandler OpenFormRequest;

   public static void  StartListening()
   {
      // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 1

      // Initialise and start worker thread
      workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenThread));
      workerThread.Start();
   }

   // A slightly modified version of the Synchronous Server Socket Example at
   // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example
   private static void  ListenThread()
   {
      // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 3

      // Opens socket and listens for command
      if (/* command received */) {
         OpenFormRequest?.Invoke();
      }
   }
}
```

The delegate callback function is run on the same thread as the socket listener.  Not the UI thread as expected.

Can anyone explain what's happening please?   I don't do a lot of .net development, so I am having trouble nutting this out.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the example is neither complete nor minimal. The `SocketListener` class is a redundant distraction IMHO, and the important stuff are hidden under the comment `// Opens socket and listens for command`.

Comment: It is #2, you can't access the Visible property on a worker thread.  You won't get an InvalidOperationException, it assumes that's what you meant to do.  You didn't, the thread does not have a dispatcher loop so the form is dead to the world with none of its events firing, including Paint.

Comment: I left out that I had actually tried calling `Invoke()` inside `OpenFormCommandHandler()`.  It made no difference, but I should have left it in to at least show that I had tried that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I can tell from the docs, the delegate should ensure that the callback is run on the UI thread. Can anyone suggest why it isn't?

There are no docs that should suggest that. I.e. it's not sufficient simply to use a delegate. You have to invoke the delegate using a mechanism that would move that invocation onto the UI thread, and there's nothing like that in the code you posted above. You seem to have misunderstood whatever it was that you read.

The issue with your code is that you appear to have confused the compiler-generated `Invoke()` method for a *delegate* with the framework-provided `Control.Invoke()` method. Your code calls the former, while you should be calling the latter. All that the former does is to actually invoke the delegate; the latter is what handles marshaling the execution of a delegate onto the UI thread so it can be executed there.

Frankly, it's a mistake for the socket-related code to try to address this at all. In the `ListenThread()` method, just raise the event normally (which ironically is the syntax you're using, so actually you don't need to change anything there). In your `OpenFormCommandHandler()` method, then you should call the `Control.Invoke()` method to execute whatever code you need to execute there, such as creating and showing a new form.

Based on your recent edit, in theory here is how you would change your event handler:

```cs
private void OpenFormCommandHandler()
{
   // Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId returns 3

   // Open the form
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Visible = true;));
}
```

But I infer from your problem description that the form has not actually been shown once yet, which means it hasn't yet been tied to main thread and so `Control.Invoke()` is unlikely to work (you'd probably get an exception reporting that the window handle hadn't been created yet…I forget the exact wording, and it's not important enough for me to go looking it up right now).

Assuming that's the case, you need to get a synchronization context from elsewhere. Unfortunately, the question still lacks the specifics that would allow a more explicit answer showing exactly how to do that. But depending on what else is going on in your program, you could:

1. Pass a different `Form` instance to the `wPrompt` constructor and use that instance when calling `Invoke()`. Or,
2. Pass [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) to the `wPrompt` constructor, and call that object's `Send()` or `Post()` method (equivalent to `Control.Invoke()` and `Control.BeginInvoke()`, respectively).

There are other mechanisms you could use to capture and then use the synchronization context, but I'd say based on the details in your question, one of those two will be preferable to you.

Comment: Well the notion of UI thread is linked to forms, so there should be at least one available to `Invoke` on it (at least the one passed as parameter to `Application.Run`).

Comment: Re docs, I misspoke a little.  I was referring to artcles [such as this one](https://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/create-a-worker-thread-for-your-windows-form-in-csharp/) which mislead by saying "to call the delegate we are using the Invoke keyword, which executes the delegate on the UI thread". I couldn't find anything more helpful. Your reference to `Control.Invoke` is the first mention I had seen of that. Thanks for the update. I will try your new suggestions now.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I went with solution number 2, since this is a single window app and there was no other Form I could use.

Comment: @XouDo: not all of the `Application.Run()` overloads require a `Form` instance. There may not always be one, even in a Winforms app.

Comment: _"which mislead by saying "to call the delegate we are using the Invoke keyword, which executes the delegate on the UI thread""_ -- yes, that article is less clear than it could be. That said, note that the object on which the `Invoke()` method is not a delegate, as in your usage, but rather the `this` reference for the `Form` object where they put the code. Frankly, that article is poor in other ways, such as mixing the UI code with the background-working code. But hopefully now the distinction is clearer.

Comment: You are calling two different `Invoke` methods if you're choosing between `this.Invoke(this.updateStatusDelegate);` and `this.updateStatusDelegate.Invoke();`. They just share the same name, but are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: The article you're quoting also suggests that you should call `Thread.Abort()`. That's a terrible idea. I would be careful about using code from that article.